# FIR filter code in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this `y(t) = ∑ W(k)*x(t-k) for k=0 to L`
I want to implement this in matlab , there W(k) is a constant matrix of 2 by 2 
while my x matrix is of 2 by 700 ...

I did like this in matlab :

```
for o=1:2
for a=1:700 
    y(o,:)=W*x(:,a);
end
end
```

Is my implementation in MATLAB correct ? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to implement a 1D FIR filter or a 2D FIR filter?

Comment: @rayryeng  hi .. if you mean by 2d that y would be 2*700 so that is what I meant , yes 2d ..thank you

Comment: @rayryeng am I doing right ?

Comment: @rayryeng  how to correct it? thanks

Comment: @rayryeng  what I do wrong in my code .. thanks